# Python Threading and SQLite Database

Tags: sql, python-3.x, multithreading

I have a SQLite database that I created with 7 columns. I am trying to/have create/created 7 threads where I want to match Thread 1 to Column 1, Thread 2 to Column 2 and generate out a list for each,but am struggling to do so.

Below is an excerpt of it with one thread.

Issues:

1. I cannot return the list (self.year) for some reason
2. Using 7 threads, they do not come in order.
3. Trying to get a fetchone of the database and have 7 threading agents grab the 7 columns in order.

How should I change my approach?

import sqlite3
import threading
import time
from queue import Queue
import queue

class Threading(threading.Thread):

```
def __init__(self,thread,q):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.lock = threading.Lock()
    self.year = []
    self.q = q
    self.thread = thread

def run(self):
    try:
        while self.q:

            fetch = self.q.get()

            with self.lock:

                if self.thread == 0:
                    self.year.append(fetch[0])

            self.q.task_done()

    except queue.Empty:
        return
```

def main():

```
threads = []
q =Queue(maxsize=0)
num_threads = 7


conn = sqlite3.connect("db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * from db")



for i in range(num_threads):

    t = Threading(i, q)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for row in c:
    q.put(row)

q.join()
```

main()

Comment: This looks like an XY problem (http://xyproblem.info/).  What is it you are really trying to do that makes threading seem like a good solution?

Comment: ^ I second this comment. What are you really trying to do?